# Add padding on blogspot title

Tags: css, styles, blogspot

Via the "Inspect Element" option of the browser, I'm able to get the needed effect with padding-left: 10px;
But adding it to the element in Theme > Edit HTML doesn't make changes.
What I'm doing wrong? 
Link to the affected page: https://oregano-design.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

May be its not updated from your server or delete your browser history. So that you can see the changes when you edit the HTML from your theme section

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by finding existing `padding-left:` attribute for the element I wanted to change and setting needed value. There was no sense to add new styles.